# How can i use Prompt to enter number of loops for macros

Tags: imacros

I'am getting this type of error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line 11 (Error code: -991).

This is my macros,

```
play = "PROMPT 'How many times to play macros?:'" !VAR1 + "\n";

for (i = 0; i < play; i++) {
    start = iimPlay(macros);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript 'prompt' dialog like this:

```
var play = 1;       // default number
play = prompt("How many times to play macros?:", play);
```